# How to send key combinations(control+shift+T) using Selenium with Ruby on Mac?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I need to send the following key combination (<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) using selenium on a Mac machine with Ruby. Someone suggest me a solution for this.

Comment: Have you tried to use `send_keys` on an arbitrary element, e.g. `body`?